# Is there any plugin to visual studio 2010 for more tools in the toolsbox?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, plugins, toolbox

Is there any plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 premium to get more tools in the toolsbox ?

Comment: Pretty much anyone can write stuff for the toolbox, it doesn't even have to be a plugin. Just drag an assembly on the toolbox. Any class that has the `ToolBoxItemAttribute` will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out DevExpress, they have a very good set of custom controls!
Not free though...